# Crear CSV automaticamente en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una función que crea un archivo .csv con datos de la base de datos y quería que se me genere automaticamente y guardarlo en una carpeta del proyecto. La cosa es que no encuentro en ningún sitio cómo se genera automaticamente, la función funciona correctamente, solo me falta eso. Muchas gracias!

Comment: tendrías que crear un cron que corra y ejecute la aplicación cada ves que tu desees.

Comment: Se te genere después de hacer que? o antes de hacer que? o sin hacer nada?

Comment: @ivanrangel Hola, gracias por responder! Se tendría que generar a una cierta hora.

Comment: aquí te enseña como: https://voragine.net/weblogs/como-ejecutar-php-periodicamente-con-cron-en-un-servidor-linux

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo Hola! El problema es que yo uso Windows...

Comment: si estas en un server windows, debieras crear una tarea programada

Comment: crea una tarea programada y cargale un archivo .bat que contenga la ruta del php que quieres ejecutar:::::::::    START "" "C:\ventas.php"  o start iexplore.exe http://localhost/archivo.php____ crea un archivo de texto y guardalo con la extencion .bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crea una tarea programada y cargale un archivo `.bat` que contenga la ruta del php que quieres ejecutar.

```
START "" "C:\ventas.php" o START iexplore.exe http://localhost/archivo.php
```

crea un archivo de texto y guardalo con la extensión `.bat`

Answer (score 3):

Si usas Linux, usa un cronjob.

1. Revisa si tienes instalado cron, quizás usando un `man cron` o un `sudo apt list --installed | grep cron` - por lo general viene instalado en cada distribución de linux -, sino está installado, instálalo con `sudo apt install cron`.
2. Crea un cronjob de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```

   y te pedirá que elijas el editor de texto con el que deseas escribir tu cronjob.
   Despues de elegir tu editor de texto, tendrás que poner la frecuencia de ejecución de tu programa seguido de tu programa en el archivo cron, algo así:

   ```
   * 18 * * *  php /ruta/a/tu/programa.php
   ```

   y "programa.php" se ejecutará todos los días a las 6 de la tarde de tu zona horaria.

Para más información sobre cronjobs consulta `man 8 cron`, `man 1 crontab` y/o `man 5 crontab`

Crontab te permite ejecutar tareas por frecuencia, algo así:

minutos horas dias meses dias_de_la_semana tu_programa
con el formato `* * * * * program`, eso lo puedes revisar en `man 5 crontab`

Si quieres ayuda con la frecuencia, puede usar esta página: https://crontab.guru/